# Visual studio error when running web app The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: .net, visual-studio, api, directory, csproj

Hope you are all enjoying coding and not meeting such a crazy error.

I am facing an error related to net6 web application when trying to run it.
Error message "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".
I have to mention that this issue appears when setting this application as startup and try to run it locally in IIS Express. However, it does work normally when it is not as startup by right clicking the project, select debug and click on start new instance.

I am developing this application using IDE: visual studio 2022 preview 17.2.0
and Target framework: Net6.

My projfile is below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <!--<OutputPath></OutputPath>-->
    <DocumentationFile>C:\HusseinApps\Master\Master.Web.Api\Master.Web.Api.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Data\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\**" />
    <Compile Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <Content Remove="Data\**" />
    <Content Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <Content Remove="Models\**" />
    <Content Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Data\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Models\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <None Remove="Data\**" />
    <None Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <None Remove="Models\**" />
    <None Remove="NewFolder\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IBaseEntity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\ICarModelRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\ICarRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IScrabRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IScrapVehicleRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IUnitOfWork.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Contracts\IUserRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Helpers\Extensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Helpers\PageList.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\CarModelRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\CarRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\Repository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\ScrapRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\ScrapVehicleRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\Repositories\UserRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Data\UnitOfWork.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="10.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="5.72.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Master.Data\Master.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```